Как в DataFrame сравнить два столбца с np.nan?
Есть DataFrame, в нем надо сравнить два столбца так, чтобы сравнение np.nan и np.nan в двух столбцах выдавало True.
Код ниже возвращает две строки.
np.nan сравнивается как False.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Город1': ['Москва', 'Ярославль', 'Псков', np.nan,1],
    'Город2': ['Москва', 'Самара', 'Ростов', np.nan,1]})
df[ df['Город1'] == df['Город2'] ]

Написать сравнение следующим образом мне не подходит:
df[ (df['Город1'] == df['Город2']) | (df['Город1'].isnull()& df['Город2'].isnull()) ]

Я хочу сделать сравнение одним условием.
Спасибо!

Судя по коду, вам надо не просто сравнить два столбца (тогда можно было бы обойтись numpy.array_equal()), а получить совпадающие строки?

Просто интересно, в какой момент среди городов появились числа?

Число добавил для сложности задачи, чтобы был и текст и число

@Евгений Если такое случается в реальной жизни, то это значит, что кто-то где-то накосячил. В идеале у каждого столбца должен быть один тип данных. Если это название города, то это строка. Отсутствие города - это пустая строка. И в такой логике задача приобретает смысл и упрощается. Когда я вижу разные типы данных вдоль столбца, то интуитивно предполагаю, что эти данные нужно транспонировать, чтобы сделать столбцы однотипными. Если же это усложнение ради усложнения, то вы рискуете получить далеко не лучший ответ на исходную задачу.

Вероятно, самый простой способ - с fillna:
res = df[df["Город1"].fillna("nan")==df["Город2"].fillna("nan")].replace("nan", np.nan)

res:
   Город1  Город2
0  Москва  Москва
3     NaN     NaN
4       1       1


Предлагаю рассмотреть вариант с использованием pandas.DataFrame.nqunique
У этого метода есть параметр dropna, который по умолчанию равен True. Нужно применить метод с dropna=False и отобрать те строки, где результат равен единице (значения nan в разных столбцах будут посчитаны как одно уникальное):
df[df[['Город1', 'Город2']].nunique('columns', dropna=False).eq(1)]

Код для экспериментов:
import pandas as pd

NA = float('nan')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Город1': ['Москва', 'Ярославль',  'Псков', NA, 1, NA, 'Иркутск'],
    'Город2': ['Москва',    'Самара', 'Ростов', NA, 1, NA, 'Иркутск'],
    'Город3': ['Москва',          NA, 'Ростов', NA, 1,  1,        NA],
})

print(df)

#       Город1  Город2  Город3
# 0     Москва  Москва  Москва
# 1  Ярославль  Самара     NaN
# 2      Псков  Ростов  Ростов
# 3        NaN     NaN     NaN
# 4          1       1       1
# 5        NaN     NaN       1
# 6    Иркутск Иркутск     NaN

cols_compare = 'Город2 Город3'.split()
selected = df[cols_compare].nunique(1, False).eq(1)
print(df.loc[selected, cols_compare])

#    Город2  Город3
# 0  Москва  Москва
# 2  Ростов  Ростов
# 3     NaN     NaN
# 4       1       1

print(df[df.nunique(1, False).eq(1)])

#    Город1  Город2  Город3
# 0  Москва  Москва  Москва
# 3     NaN     NaN     NaN
# 4       1       1       1

